# Unable to show a loading message when new screen is generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

So I have an webpage in which, for the click of a button I do a lengthy computation (in client side JS) and show the results in a a new layer. I want it such that I show a loading... message when the computation is running. So I did the following:

```
$('#loader').html("<div class='loader-info'>Loading...</div>");
_.defer(doComputation);
```

The `doComputation` is a function that does my lengthy calculations. I also tried `setTimeout(doComputation,0);` instead of the underscore defer. In both cases, sometimes the loading layer is shown and in most cases it is not! I am not sure how the JS engine decides on this.

I am looking for a stable solution, where everytime I press the calc button the loading... message is shown. The computation takes a few minutes and so it is necessary to show this message to the user.

How can I achieve this? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have should work. Can you post your `doCoputation` function? Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/of6uqpyp/

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class='loader-info'>Loading...</div>

$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 $("#loader-info").hide();
});
```